# how to reload web page on click back button of browser in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, browser, browser-cache

I have problem regarding back button of browser. Click of back button I want to reload my web page but it doesn't post-back that's why I am not able to refresh page. I have used following code to clean cache but it shows me your page expired but I want to refresh it.

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(Now.AddSeconds(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

I am also trying to disable back button of browser through javascript but it could not work.
code for javascript is

```
window.history.forward();
function noBack(){ window.history.forward(); }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842356/asp-net-c-sharp-navigate-back-reload-page may be help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create history point and save them to the browser
here is a walk-through by microsoft
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488548%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I want to refresh my repeater which i have used in web page but on click of browser back button it is not postback it shows page as it like previously shown. Please tell me how to reload web page i don't want to save history.